# Android : Adding custom view to child of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview, scrollview, android-custom-view

I am having problem with ScrollView when I try to add custom view to child(RelativeLayout) of ScrollView. **It works correctly when I remove scrollView.**

Here's xml file

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:id="@+id/rlSelectable">
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view1"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view2"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view3"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view4"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view5"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view6"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view5" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view7"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view6"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view8"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view7"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view9"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view8"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view10"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view9"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view11"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view10"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view12"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view11"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view13"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view12"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view14"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view13"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view15"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view14"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:id="@+id/view16"
              android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
              android:layout_below="@+id/view6"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Note: ScrollView is not parent in xml layout. It's wrapped in RelativeLayout.

Here's MainActivity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Dragger.DraggerInterface {

GestureDetector detector;
ArrayList<Dragger> draggers;
RelativeLayout rlSelectable;
int width,height,count=0,startsAt=0;
float centerX;
ScrollView scrollView;
String TAG = "MAIN_DRAGGER";

View view;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_view);

    view = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    rlSelectable = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlSelectable);
    draggers = new ArrayList<Dragger>();
    scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    detector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            int index  = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(e);
            float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(e, index);
            float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(e, index);
            addDragger(centerX,y);
            log("single tapped");
            return true;
        }
    });




    rlSelectable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    width = rlSelectable.getWidth();
    centerX = (rlSelectable.getRight()-rlSelectable.getLeft())/2;
    height = view.getHeight();
    startsAt = view.getTop();
}


public void addDragger(float x,float y) {
    Dragger dragger = new Dragger(MainActivity.this);
    dragger.setParams(width,height);
    dragger.setCenter(x, y);
    draggers.add(dragger);
    dragger.setId(count++);
    dragger.viewStartsAt(startsAt);
    dragger.addView(this);
    rlSelectable.addView(dragger);

}




private void log(String message){
    Log.d(TAG,message);
}

@Override
public void checkBounds(Dragger current) {
    int currentId = current.getId();

    if(draggers.size()>1){
        for(Dragger dragger : draggers){

            if(currentId !=dragger.getId()){
                if(current.getUpState() && current.getRectTop()<dragger.getRectBootom() && current.getRectBootom() > dragger.getRectTop()){
                    dragger.setBottom(current.getRectBootom());
                    current.removeView();
                    draggers.remove(current);
                    break;
                }else if(!current.getUpState() && current.getRectBootom() > dragger.getRectTop() && current.getRectTop() < dragger.getRectBootom()){
                    dragger.setTop(current.getRectTop());
                    current.removeView();
                    draggers.remove(current);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the major problem with your code is having wrap_content for scrollView and match_parent for child of scrollView which should be opposite to what you have implemented. try doing that! Have wrap_content for height of Relative layout.

Comment: can you explain more about your problem, like your app crash or your scrollview won't scroll, ...

Comment: @PhanVănLinh when I try to add custom view that I created to only relative layout without scrollview as its parent, the addview is working but when I try to add it with scrollview as parent it doesnt add the custom view to relativelayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"> <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_id"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_id">

    </LinearLayout>

   <ScrollView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:id="@+id/rlSelectable">
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view4"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view5"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view4" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view6"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view5" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view7"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view8"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view7"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view9"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view8"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view10"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view9"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view11"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view10"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view12"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view11"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view13"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view12"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view14"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view13"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view15"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view14"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/view16"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_corner_curved"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ,i tried on my device it's working.

Comment: its throwing nullpointerexception boolean android.graphics.RectF.contains(float, float)' on a null object reference

Comment: somewhere you are not making the object and trying to put the value inside it .

Comment: if that was the case I would get error in previous layout as well.. Only when I change my xml to your solution it gives me this error. Can you explain whats wrong with my original xml?

Comment: can you please comment out your code in AppCompatActivity for some time and only try to inflate view with the above layout that i given to you.